# Apache can't load utf8 python file

Tags: python, django, apache, utf-8

I use Django web framework to develope my website. My python file in my project is as below

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def index(request):
     model = MyModel.objects.all()[0]
     if model.name == 'é':
          return HttpResponse("True")
     else
          return HttpResponse("False")
```

My 'name' variable is always 'é' but it returns false.

I use Apache 2.2 and python 2.7.3 to load my web app by mod_wsgi as [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/deployment/modwsgi/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if model.name == u'é':
```

char limit...